# New keyframes are changing old ones automatically

Tags: transforms, keyframes, rigify

I set a few keys with an armature.  If I try to rotate transform along an axis between the last two keys....it rotates other keys set before as well.  I tried just moving my spine bone backwards and the spine is backwards on all my previous keys.

I select everything with A for rotation and only a single bone to bend spine

My goal is for my keyframes not to change after setting them but if anything, I’d really just like to know why new keys effect old ones?

- I’m using blender 2.79 and I reset factory settings.  I added a metarig armature (with and without adding rigify controls)*

Comment: maybe create some keyframes before the one you want to create?

Comment: Try to replicate your workflow with a new file with something simple. If that is happening again share this file via https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Ok it looks like keyframes were not being set for all the channels making it appear like old keyframes were being overridden.  Looking for tutorials explaining the keyframe menu....like what is a visual keyframe.   Wondering if an option is available to key every possible channel for the armature